# bash: a for loop does not increment by 1. How can I treat it like it does in order to get the index (1, 2, 3, etc) of each loop?

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, iterator

I have this loop that allows me to deal only with certain time steps from a simulation:

```
    let ALLSTEPS=820000
    for ((step=20000; step <= ALLSTEPS; step+=20000)); do
        echo "Step: $step"
...
```

Within the loop I need to read in a row from each line of an external file.  This is what I have:

```
i=$((step));
k=$(sed "${i}q;d" externalFile.txt)
echo ${k%}
```

This does not work because in the external file, my rows go: 1, 2, 3, 4, etc whereas "step" is "20000, 40000, 60000, ..."

I could set up another loop but that seems unwieldy and I wonder if there's a cleaner way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use multiple variables per arithmetic for loop:

```
ALLSTEPS=820000
for ((i=1, step=20000; step <= ALLSTEPS; i++, step+=20000)); do
    echo "Step: $step, i: $i"
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using `sed` (which will read through the entire file, just to pick out a single line), why not use `read` in the loop to read the next line each time through?

```
for ((step=20000; step <= ALLSTEPS; step+=20000)); do
    IFS= read -r k <&3    # Read the next line from the external file
    echo "Step: $step, k: $k"
    ...
done 3<externalFile.txt
```

In the above, I used FD #3 for the file (the `3<` and `<&3` stuff), to avoid conflicts with standard input if anything else in the loop reads from that.

(And the `IFS=` and `-r` stuff in the `read` command are standard ways to tell `read` to just read the raw lines, don't "helpfully" preprocess them.)

Comment: I had never heard of read.  Thank you; my files are huge and I do notice that this is faster.

Comment: @Ant `read`'s generally the best way to process a file line-by-line in bash; it can also split fields into separate variables if that's appropriate. See [BashFAQ #1: How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: that's really helpful.  Thank you so much for taking the time.